# Is it possible to load new div content after reaching last panel in stepcarousel? Non-Dynamic?

Tags: javascript, ajax, carousel

I think you are familiar with the "stepcarousel.js" script; but I wonder if the whole script can run on a fixed data storage or if you call a function it can continue fliping?

See what I am trying to do:

```
stepcarousel.setup({
    [...style setup...]

    contenttype: ['inline'], 

    oninit:function(){
        contentcontainer=document.getElementById('related')
    },

    onslide:function(){ 
        var d1 = document.getElementById('related'); 
        d1.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div id="two">two</div>');
    }
})
```

So, when it reaches the end of the panel, it displays the "two" txt but does not create a independent panel, so there will be a last panel with a lot of "two".

What I want to do is, to create a new panel, but it seems stepcarousel only reads the number of "div"s onload but not, like, new divs when calling `insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', ...)`...

any guess??!